# How to create a new menu item and call the selected code

Tags: java, object, menuitem, bluej

Create a new menu item for the project imageviewer1-0 called blur. When the item from the menu is selected the code for the makeBlur method needs to be called.

This is what I have right now. I am not sure how to call the makeblur method so that it is run when the menu item is selected.

```
private void makeBlur()
{
if(currentImage != null) {

// Create the kernel.
float filter[] = { 0.1111f, 0.1111f, 0.1111f,
0.1111f, 0.1111f, 0.1111f,
0.1111f, 0.1111f, 0.1111f };
Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, filter);
ConvolveOp op = new ConvolveOp(kernel);
// Create the convolve operation.

BufferedImage img = op.filter(currentImage, null);
currentImage = new OFImage(img);
imagePanel.clearImage();
imagePanel.setImage(currentImage);
frame.repaint();
showStatus("Applied: blur");
}
else {
showStatus("No image loaded.");

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
System.out.println("Menu item: " + event.getActionCommand());
}


private void makeFrame() 
frame = new JFrame("ImageViewer"); 
makeMenuBar(Frame);




private void makeMenuBar(JFrame frame) 

JMenuBar();
frame.setJmenuBar(menubar);

Jmenu fileMenu = new Jmenu("File"); 
menubar.add(fileMenu);

JMenuItem openItem = JMenuItem("Open"); 
openItem.addActionListener(this); 
fileMenu.add(openItem); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
JMenuItem blur = new JMenuItem();
        blur.setText("Blur");
        blur.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                makeBlur();
            }
        });
        menubar.add(blur);
```